# How can I view more info on a file copy progress from 18.04 "Files" GUI?

Tags: 18.04, filemanager, copy

I am using cut and paste within the file browser GUI in 18.04 to move data from one drive to another. There is a progress menu where I can view the progress of this operation:

[image: progress of copy operation]

As you can see there is only a limited amount of info available due to the small size of the menu.

**How can I see an expanded view of the *moving files to "Data Mine"* process?**

Something similar to the "Show All Downloads" window in Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: The bottom section looks truncated. Have you tried grabbing the bottom window border and pulling it down? Sorry I can't test this myself right now.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don't think he is asking about the truncated progress bar only. In my opinion OP wants to see other details like out of those 204K files while file is currently being copied/moved.

Comment: @Kulfy If memory serves me correct below the truncated portion is a down arrow you can select for more details. But memory is faulty at times. Still it would be nice to pull the bottom window border down to reveal the whole panel and see what else is there.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix In my case I can use mouse scroll to see that truncated details and other progresses. And yes selecting do nothing. No more details are there other than shown in screenshot.

Comment: I can't resize the menu window... I have moved mouse cursor to every spot on menu border.... scrolling shows other actions but I want to see all the data on that BIG transfer... even just whats showing after the .....

Comment: If you copy with `rsync` (from a terminal window), you can view the progress in various ways. See `man rsync` which is a long and detailed manual. You can also find tutorials about `rsync` via the internet. there is also a GUI version, `grsync`.

Comment: @sudodus thanks for the suggestion... I would rather just use gnome files... I was hoping there was something similar to "show all downloads" in a web browser... is installing another program my only option?

Comment: `rsync` is bundled with Ubuntu. You need *not* install it. (But `grsync` must be installed.) I use `rsync` and I like it :-)

Comment: I have use rsync for backups and ssh syncing.... however I like the ease of just copy/paste in file browser.... just to bad there isn't an expanded view of the progress menu

Comment: I'm aware this is old but I am interested in this (asking again would be duplicate). What parameters are you searching exactly? Speed? percentage?

Comment: Are you interested only in Nautilus/Files or in other file managers too?